# How can I fire a function in headerRight using Formik?

Tags: react-native, formik

I'm new to react-native and formik and I encountered this problem that I'm trying to build up.

How can I fire a function in headerRight using Formik? I have updateCorporation function that will do fire api, and formik will do the job to fire this function and after I press the Update button, but the results are undefined
I didn`t understand why its happening.

File_1.js

```
const CorporationContainer = (props) => {
    const {
    navigation,
} = props;

const updateCorporation = (values) => {
    // do patch stuff with values
    // but its undefined
};

useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({ updateCorporation: updateCorporation.bind() });
}, []);

return (
    <Corporation
        updateCorporation={updateCorporation} />
    );
};

CorporationContainer.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerRight: (
        <EditBtn
        onPress={() => navigation.state.params.updateCorporation()}
        >
        <EditText>Update</EditText>
        </EditBtn>
    ),
});

export default CorporationContainer;
```

File_2.js

```
const Corporation = (props) => {
    const {
        updateCorporation,
    } = props;

    const emailField = useRef(null);

    const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
        email: yup.string()
        .ensure()
        .email('Email must be valid')
        .required('Email'),
    });

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{
                email,
            }}
            onSubmit={values => updateCorporation(values)}
            validateOnBlur={false}
            validateOnChange={false}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            >
        {(formProps) => {
            const {
            errors,
            setFieldValue,
            values,
            } = formProps;
            return (
                <Container>
                    <Input
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="Email Corporation"
                        textContentType="emailAddress"
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                        returnKeyType="done"
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        ref={emailField}
                        value={values.email}
                        onChangeText={setFieldValue}
                        editable={!email}
                        error={errors.email}}
                    />
                </Container>
            );
        }}
        </Formik>
    );
};

export default Corporation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In File_1.js I had to use `withForm` and remove all Formik things in File_2.js and use the props instead.

```
const CorporationContainer = (props) => {
    const {
        navigation,
        handleSubmit,
        errors,
        setFieldValue,
        values,
    } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setParams({ updateCorporation: handleSubmit.bind() });
    }, []);

    return (
        <ProfileProfessional
        errors={errors}
        setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
        values={values}
        />
    );
};

CorporationContainer.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
headerRight: (
    <EditBtn
    onPress={() => navigation.state.params.updateCorporation()}
    >
    <EditText>Editar</EditText>
    </EditBtn>
),
});

export default withFormik({
    // ...
})(CorporationContainer);
```

Comment: hi it could be fine to see all dependencies you need inside your files

Answer (score 0):

Formik author here...

Haven't tried this out, and idk exactly how navigation binding works, but you want to bind Formik's `submitForm()` prop to the navigation and not the `updateCorporation` function. However, You will need to do this where you have access to Formik props/context (i.e. as a child of `<Formik>`).

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'formik'

const updateCorporation = (values) => {
    // do patch stuff with values
    // but its undefined
};

const BindSubmit = connect(({ formik, navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({ updateCorporation: submitForm.bind() });
   }, []);
  return null
})


// ... and then just render it somewhere under Formik

const Corporation = () => {
 return (
   <Formik>
    <BindSubmit />
    {/* ... same */}
   </Formik>
 )
}
```

Comment: the best solution that I found is use to withFormik for higher order.

Comment: @fsi do you have an example withFormik that include any dynamic navigationOptions header button ? cause i just open i close question here https://t.ly/LdYzn