# How use formik from Header / navigationOptions and trigger handleSubmit onpress HeaderRight

Tags: react-native, formik

#### the goal

pass params to navigation in order to get access to

```js
onPress={props.handleSubmit}
```

within a simple react Natie app, 
inside `#EditProductScreen.js`

I have this pattern

```js
//import
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
...
import { Formik, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
...

//compnt
const EditProductScreen = props => {
...
}

//Navigation
EditProductScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
...
};

//Style
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  form: {
    margin: 20
  },
...
});

export default EditProductScreen;
```

I saw these issue and answer but unfortunately can't figure out the correct way to what I need
here the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56675671/7800866)
and here answer [jaredpalmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2938974/jaredpalmer)

This link could also be very close to [the targeted pattern](https://t.ly/Zb0mx)
however, no navigationOptions have been added to that example

I have a serious issue (cause can't figure the NavigationOption setup with formik) to use trick you provide there
here a screenshot that explains the goal
[image]

#### dive inside main cmpnt and Navigation

`#cpnt`

```js
const EditProductScreen = props => {
   //some code 
   ...

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ title: title, email: '' }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          title: Yup.string()
            .min(2, 'Too Short!')
            .max(50, 'Too Long!')
            .required('Required')
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
          submitHandler();
        }}
      >
        {props => (
          <View>
            <View style={styles.form}>
              <View style={styles.formControl}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Title</Text>
                <TextInput
                  // some code
                />

              // some code

              </View>
            </View>
            <Button
              title={'submit'}
              onPress={props.handleSubmit}
              color='black'
              mode='contained'
              loading={props.isSubmitting}
              disabled={props.isSubmitting}
              style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

`#navigation`

```js
EditProductScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
  const submitFn = navData.navigation.getParam('submit');
  return {
    headerTitle: navData.navigation.getParam('productId')
      ? 'Edit Product'
      : 'Add Product',
    headerRight: (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title='Save'
          iconName={
            Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-checkmark' : 'ios-checkmark'
          }
          onPress={submitFn}
          // here the challenge 

        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    )
  };
};
```

so here I am, 
I try to build something like this inside

#### what i guess

create a useEffect

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: handleSubmit.bind() });
    }, []);
```

and call it from the navigation... but how even call handleSubmit in this useEffect ? how seriuosly define handleSubmit before, in order to use it inside the useEffect?

let's say that I succeed to build that useEffect

then call it from navigation

```js
EditProductScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
const submitForValidation = navData.navigation.getParam('handleSubmit');
// some code 
    headerRight: (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item
          // some code 
          onPress={submitForValidation}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    )
}
```

I did a snack fo my current code if it helps to help.
[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@vbaxt/formik-and-navigationheader)

Comment: you have to use hoc. you must remove your formik tag and use withFormik function, i used the jared example: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withformik

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the same issue, and come up with below workaround.

**First, remove this line**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: handleSubmit.bind() });
    }, []);
```

**Second, set reference to header from Formik children render**

```
const EditProductScreen = props => {
    //some code 
    ...

return (
    <ScrollView>
        <Formik
            initialValues={{ title: title, email: '' }}
            validationSchema={Yup.object({
                title: Yup.string()
                    .min(2, 'Too Short!')
                    .max(50, 'Too Long!')
                    .required('Required')
            })}
            onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
                submitHandler();
            }}
        >
            {props => {

                // ***************************************
                // ADDED THIS LINE TO PASS PARAM TO HEADER
                // ***************************************
                navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: props.handleSubmit });

                return (
                    <View>
                        <View style={styles.form}>
                            <View style={styles.formControl}>
                                <Text style={styles.label}>Title</Text>
                                <TextInput
   ..... the rest
```

**I think there might be other better solution like passing Formik's ref or so that you need to find out more**

Comment: thanks for your answer @Ponleu. if I build your proposition, which could be elegant at the end...that doesn't sound good like this. Red screen => can't find variable: navigation if changing it by props.navigation.setParams I also have red screen which ask me to investigate there

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HOC and wrap your form with withFormik.

Here's an example

```js
const sendDataToAPI = (values,options) => {
  //save data 
}

const formWrapper = withFormik({
  enableReinitialize: true,
  mapPropsToValues: props => ({}),
  validationSchema: yup.object().shape({
    title: yup.string().required("field is required"),
    
  }),
  validate: (values, props) => {
    let errors = {}
    return errors
  },
  handleSubmit: (values,actions) => {
   sendDataToAPI(values,actions)
  },
})


const form = props => {
  const {
    values,
    actions,
    handleSubmit,
    setFieldValue,
    navigation,
    status
  } = props;
  
  React.useEffect(() => { 
      navigation.setParams({ 
          saveForm: handleSubmit
      }) 
  }, [])

  return (
   <SafeAreaView>
    <View >
        {status && status.hasOwnProperty('errors') && (
             <View>
                 <Text>{status.errors}</Text>
             </View>
         )}
        <View>
            <Text>Title</Text>
            <Field component={FKTextInput} name="title" />
        </View>
    </View>

  </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
form.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
 return {
  headerLeft: (
            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
             <Text>Cancel</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        ),
        headerRight: (
            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.state.params.saveForm()}}>
                <Text>Save</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        ),
       
        title: 'Save product'
 }
}

export default formWrapper(form)
```